# libjvm.so is not found in the bundled runtime

Tags: java, javafx

i am beginner in java and i want to run a java excutable (which is odin linux version ) that i've found in this [post](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/utility-odin-for-linux-jodin3-casual.3777030/) so when i extracted the zip file i found it as follow :[image]

so what the post said is to install at least java 8 and i have both java 8 and 11 and just to make sure I've switched to java 8 :
[image]

then when i run `JOdin3CASUAL` i got this error :

```
libjvm.so is not found in the bundled runtime.
Failed to launch JVM
```

when i searched for the lib in my java lib i found it in this path :

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server
```

so then i tried to run the `jar` in `app` folder i got this error :

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
```

**note** : my javaFX version is `javafx-sdk-11.0.2`
any help is appreciated

Comment: You can't mix and match JavaFX with JDKs. Make your life much easier. Download and install [Liberica OpenJDK 8](https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/#/java-8-lts).

Comment: still having the same problem